# Get the max of each group when using groupby() on two columns ~Python

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, pandas-groupby

Using a csv in a similar format (total csv is ~500 x ~600,000), so there are columns missing:

```
       Sales  market_id  product_id

0         38   10001516     1132679
1         49   10001516     1138767
2          6   10001516     1132679
     ...        ...         ...
9969  245732    1002123     1383020
9970  247093    1006821     1383020
```

etc
and reading it in like so:
`df0=pd.read_csv('all_final_decomps2_small.csv', low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859_15')`

I'm trying to find the product_id per each market_id with the maximum sales. To do this I need to sum the sales as the same product_id and market_id can appear in multiple rows.

I have tried this which yields the sum of products within each market:

```
df_sales=df0[['Sales','market_id','product_id']] 
df_sales.groupby(['market_id', 'product_id'])['Sales'].sum()
```

As so (shortened):

```
market_id  product_id
1006174    1132679             2789
           1382460             4586
           1382691               49
           1383020        269138089
1006638    1132679          5143156
           1382460           387250
           1383020        204456809
10002899   1132679              630
           1382464              220
```

using:

```
df_sales.groupby(['market_id', 'product_id'])['Sales'].sum().max()
```

returns the maximum value of the sums and nothing else, so in this instance it would return 269138089. I would like to return something like this:

```
market_id  product_id      max_sales
1006174    1383020        269138089
1006638    1383020        204456809
10002899   1132679              630
```

I've tried a lot of different things but I can't seem to get anything to work for this example, so I'd appreciate any help (and sorry if it seems like it's been asked before).

I am using:
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Use `idxmax` within a `groupby`

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """market_id  product_id         Sales
1006174    1132679             2789
1006174    1382460             4586
1006174    1382691               49
1006174    1383020        269138089
1006638    1132679          5143156
1006638    1382460           387250
1006638    1383020        204456809
10002899   1132679              630
10002899   1382464              220"""


sales = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=[0, 1], squeeze=True)
```

**Solution**

```
sales.loc[sales.groupby(level=0).idxmax()]

market_id  product_id
1006174    1383020       269138089
1006638    1383020       204456809
10002899   1132679             630
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
sales.loc[sales.groupby(level=0).idxmax()].reset_index(name='max_sales')

   market_id  product_id  max_sales
0    1006174     1383020  269138089
1    1006638     1383020  204456809
2   10002899     1132679        630
```

Comment: Copying your code, it runs fine and as required. However, I have issues with creating the dataframe from the file using this method. The actual csv is approximately 10,000 x 500, which is a smaller version of 600,000 x 500 (so I can't read in as text in quotes). This is my current read line: df0=pd.read_csv('exampledb.csv', low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859_15') Any idea how I can change your code to work for that? Trying to specify the columns 'market_id' and 'product_id'as indexes after creating a dataframe results in an indexing a multi-index error

Comment: @ebrithilotho My `sales` object is what I believe you should have in your `df_sales`... I just used my `pd.read_csv` to show how I got to that point because you didn't provide adequate data.  You should be able to run my code on your `df_sales`.

Comment: Using this line: `df_sales.loc[df_sales.groupby(level=0).idxmax()].reset_index(name='max_sales'` is where I'm having issues. Using my read line, it presents: `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`. If I change my read line to add `index_col=['market_id','product_id']` it causes the same error. They aren't columns 0,1 in the table (they are mixed in with 500 other variables) so I would like to be able to reference them by name. I know your code works on it's own but I'm struggling to apply it to my file. If I didn't give adequate data is there anything other info that could help?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to get this - I'm not sure if its the best way to do it but it works with my data:

```
df0=pd.read_csv('test.csv', low_memory=False, encoding='iso8859_15')

#Rank all items in each market by total sales
df_sales=df0[['Sales', 'market_id', 'product_id']] # int, int, int

# groups sales by market and product and sums product sales
gr_sales = df_sales.groupby(['market_id', 'product_id'], as_index = False).sum()

# gets the product sales in each market and sorts in order of decreasing sales
gr_sales = gr_sales.groupby('market_id').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'Sales', ascending = False)

# Finds the product id with the maximum sales in each market
max_sales = gr_sales.groupby('market_id').max()
```

Giving me:

```
In[621]: max_sales
Out[621]: 
    market_id  product_id       Sales
0     1006174     1383020   269138089
1     1006638     1383020  1330070614
2     1006678     1383020    58548417
3     1006684     1383020   215858049
4     1006692     1383020    21799689
5     1006732     1383020    58548417
6     1006733     1383020    58548417
7     1006739     1383020   215858049
8     1006819     1383020   605951504
9     1006820     1383020    59083807
10    1006821     1383020    25116872
11    1050511     1382672     6201692
12    1050512     1382672     5468317
13   10001493     1383020    21799689
14   10001516     1383020   204456809
15   10002899     1383020    62413425
```

and (shortened example):

```
In[624]: gr_sales
Out[624]: 
               market_id  product_id       Sales
market_id                                       
1006174   11     1006174     1383020   269138089
          9      1006174     1382672     5070111
          5      1006174     1382536     2442639
          7      1006174     1382602     1108361
          6      1006174     1382557      158488
          8      1006174     1382651       17214
          1      1006174     1382460        4586
          0      1006174     1132679        2789
          3      1006174     1382490         799
          2      1006174     1382464         105
          10     1006174     1382691          49
          4      1006174     1382522          16
1006638   28     1006638     1383020  1330070614
          25     1006638     1382672   109679596
          12     1006638     1132679     5143156
          17     1006638     1382536     4885278
          22     1006638     1382620     2668948
          21     1006638     1382602     2216722
          18     1006638     1382538      992228
          13     1006638     1382460      387250
          19     1006638     1382557      316976
          23     1006638     1382651       39616
          26     1006638     1382674       22388
          20     1006638     1382573        7412
          15     1006638     1382490        1598
          14     1006638     1382464         758
          24     1006638     1382665         120
          27     1006638     1382691          98
          16     1006638     1382522          32
1006678   32     1006678     1383020    58548417
                 ...         ...         ...

[117 rows x 3 columns]
```

I'm not sure how to remove the arbitrary index from the gr_sales output though (right in the middle like that is a bit annoying), or from the max_sales table